# Реализация страницы price-list. Выборка из базы данных

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, phpmyadmin

Всем привет! Есть задача, которую я не знаю как можно реализовать правильно и оптимально. У меня есть страница с прайс-листом. И мне нужно правильно представить таблицы в базе данных для выборки. На странице у меня есть drop-down-list в который я должен положить главный документ к которому привязана услуга. Внутри этого drop list-та у меня услуги разделяются на еще одни блоки, каждая услуга относиться к своей специфики. Drop-down-list должен быть один, но внутри него может быть несколько специфик и к каждой специфики много услуг. Как можно реализовать данную задачу. У меня есть мысль как сделать ее с помощью 3 таблиц, но я не уверен, что смогу правильно связать их и получить результат. Может у кого-то будет более оптимальный вариант. Спасибо заранее[image: Прайс лист]

Пример вёрстки

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="tables">
            <div class="tables-item">
              <div class="tables-header">
                <div class="title">Сертификаты и декларации соответствия</div>
                <div class="arrow"> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="tables-content">
                <div class="table-mobile">
                  <div class="title">Наименование регламента (продукции); cтоимость (руб.)</div>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="title-mobile">Сертификаты соответствия техническим регламентам Таможенного союза</li>
                    <li>ТР ТС 004/2011 «О безопасности низковольтного оборудования» <span class="prices">от 21 000 руб.</span></li>
                    <li>ТР ТС 007/2011 «О безопасности продукции, предназначенной для детей и подростков» <span class="prices">от 19 500 руб.</span></li>
                    <li>ТР ТС 008/2011 «О безопасности игрушек» <span class="prices">от 19 500 руб.</span></li>
                    <li>ТР ТС 010/2011 «О безопасности машин и оборудования» <span class="prices">от 21 000 руб.</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Наименование регламента (продукции)</th>
                      <th>Стоимость (руб.)</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr class="title">
                      <td colspan="2">Сертификаты соответствия техническим регламентам Таможенного союза</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>ТР ТС 004/2011 «О безопасности низковольтного оборудования»</td>
                      <td>от 21 000 руб.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>ТР ТС 007/2011 «О безопасности продукции, предназначенной для детей и подростков»</td>
                      <td>от 19 500 руб.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>ТР ТС 004/2011 «О безопасности низковольтного оборудования»</td>
                      <td>от 21 000 руб.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>ТР ТС 004/2011 «О безопасности низковольтного оборудования»</td>
                      <td>от 21 000 руб.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>ТР ТС 004/2011 «О безопасности низковольтного оборудования»</td>
                      <td>от 21 000 руб.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>ТР ТС 004/2011 «О безопасности низковольтного оборудования»</td>
                      <td>от 21 000 руб.</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tables-item">
              <div class="tables-header">
                <div class="title">Свидетельства о государственной регистрации</div>
                <div class="arrow"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="tables-content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tables-item">
              <div class="tables-header">
                <div class="title">Другие документы</div>
                <div class="arrow"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="tables-content"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если првильно понял, то достаточно двух таблиц:

1. **специфики**

   - поля: только имя
   - связь: hasMany(имеет много услуг)
2. **услуги специфики**,

   - поля: имя, цена, table1_id(используется для связи между таблицами)
   - связь: belongsTo(имеет специфику)

Если У Вас много таких выпадающих листов которые имеют свои спецификации, то можно сделать таблицы по такому принципу: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through